# FindsBug Warning:A prepared statement is generated from a nonconstant String

Tags: java, sql, findbugs

I'm getting the findsbug warning like "A prepared statement is generated from a nonconstant String".My Scenerio like

```
//My code
 public static int updateSQL(String sql) throws StoreException {      
      PreparedStatement statement = null;
      statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);  //shows violation here
}
```

I'm getting "sql" through argument of the method.how to rectify this warning?Kindly help me to fix this issue.

Comment: PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql); ?

Comment: [Doc](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#SQL_PREPARED_STATEMENT_GENERATED_FROM_NONCONSTANT_STRING) warns about the possible sql injection, solutions and alternate options are discussed in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10500305/how-to-avoid-security-a-prepared-statement-is-generated-from-a-nonconstant-st)

Answer (score 1):

Well, in this case I'd suggest to ignore this warning. It has low priority. The low-priority reports for this particular bug pattern are actually mostly junk. To my opinion it should not be reported as FindBugs is capable to go step further and see whether the `updateSQL` method is always called with constant string (in this case you have no problems) or not (in this case the specific places where non-constant string is used will be reported). I filed a [bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/findbugs/bugs/1416/) to our tracker.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not a serious warning. I got the same warning while trying to use a SQL query which a part of it is dynamic(Changes with the occasion). There is not a proper way to avoid this scenario. So you can just avoid it.